# reading two lists in loop and check one by whole list

Tags: bash, loops, heredoc, nmap

I am writing a bash with two ways and there is a problem:

1)

```
#!/bin/bash              
if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage: ./nmap <port-range> <ip-list>"
    exit 1
fi

OUT=`nmap -p $1 --script=http-headers.nse $2 | tail -n 13 | head -n 1 | awk -F: '{print $2}'`

awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next}{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i in a) {print $i} } } ' $1 $2
    if [ $OUT == 'Apache' ]; then
        echo right
    else
        echo wrong
    fi
```

2)

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
echo "Usage: ./nmap <port-range> <ip-list>"
exit 1
fi

OUT=`nmap -p $1 --script=http-headers.nse $2 | tail -n 13 | head -n 1 | awk -F: '{print$2}'`

while IFS= read -r LINE; do           
grep "$LINE" $2                       
if [ $OUT == 'Apache' ]; then
   echo right
else
   echo wrong
fi
```

I have two arguments: ports.txt  ip.txt

```
cat ports.txt
80
443

cat ip.txt
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
```

I want to check each ip with all ports one by one..

any idea?

Than you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect each file on a different file descriptor:

```
while read -r -u3 port; do
    while read -r -u4 ip; do

        # do stuff with $port and $ip
        echo -n "$ip $port: "
        OUT=$( nmap -p "$port" --script=http-headers.nse "$ip" |
               tail -n 13 | 
               awk -F: '{print $2; exit}' )
        [[ $OUT == Apache ]] && echo right || echo wrong

    done 4< "$2"
done 3< "$1"
```

Comment: You don't need `head` in your pipeline: awk can exit after reading the first line.

Comment: thank you...but there is a problem.my result is Apache but the out put in script show me "wrong" the following command works while script no: nmap -p 80 --script=http-headers.nse www.test.com | tail -n 13 | awk -F: '{print $2; exit}'

Comment: test with `echo ">$OUT<"` to see if there is leading or trailing whitespace. You might want `[[ $OUT == *Apache* ]]` to test if the output *contains* "Apache"

Comment: what you said worked as well..thank you very much :)